# Showing an image with the topic in table of contents in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics, table-of-contents, backgrounds

In beamer, there is a facility to show the table of contents slide each time I switch to a new section, where the new section will be lighted and others dimmed. Can I find a way of showing an image along with the highlighted section ?

It needn't necessarily be a background image, even one with simple `\includegraphics{...}` will do. I am using the theme Juan-Les-Pins.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that illustrates your problem. It is considered a lot better to put in some code that will compile, as it makes it a lot easier for us to copy it into our text editor and work with it, and see exactly what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: This question should not have been closed. The last sentence is PERHAPS too localized, but it has nothing to do with the core of the question. I would love to answer this question and I think it would be very useful.